# Openlayers map with marker and fullscreen control

Tags: openlayers-3

I am using OpenLayers 3.5.0 to embed a map in my website, and place a marker overlay at specific coordinates. I've also added a fullscreen control. Both work individually, but in full-screen mode the marker is no longer at the specified coordinates. It also moves around when panning instead of staying fixed to one map position.

Here's the code that sets up the map:

```
function map(lon, lat) {
    var coords = ol.proj.fromLonLat([lon, lat], 'EPSG:3857');
    var layer = new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM()
    });
    var map = new ol.Map({
        controls: ol.control.defaults().extend([
            new ol.control.FullScreen()
        ]),
        layers: [ layer ],
        target: 'map',
        view: new ol.View({
            maxZoom: 19,
            zoom: 15,
            center: coords
        }),
        interactions: ol.interaction.defaults({mouseWheelZoom:false})
    });
    map.addOverlay(new ol.Overlay({
        position: coords,
        positioning: 'bottom-center',
        element: $('<img>')
            .addClass('location-popover')
            .attr('src', 'pin.jpg')
    }));
}
```

Is there a way I can make the overlay play nicely in full-screen mode?

Comment: Can't reproduce this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with the popovers/markers being in the wrong position.  Not sure if it's the same thing you're experiencing but in my case I was appending data to the page along with the markers, and this was adding a scrollbar to the window.  This affected the positioning, so what I had to do was call

```
map.updateSize();
```

after I was done adding everything.  After that everything lined up correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, unfortunately it did not help in my case. I was able to resolve the issue by upgrading to the latest release of OL3, though.